# DataFrame.loc() do pandas não encontra o registro

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Bom dia!

Estou tentando manipular um DataFrame que tem origem em um relatório DRE (contabilidade). Gostaria o index fosse o código da conta, o que já consegui fazer. Apesar disso, DataFrame.loc[] não encontra o registro. Segue:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
from pandas import DataFrame

dre = pd.read_csv('/home/andre/Documentos/ambev_dre3.csv', names=['Conta',   'Descrição', '2017', '2016', '2015'], dtype={'Conta':str})
dre = dre.set_index('Conta')
dre
```

[image: DRE]

Ocorre que `dre.loc['3.02']` retorna erro:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _validate_key(self, key, axis)
   1789                 if not ax.contains(key):
-> 1790                     error()
   1791             except TypeError as e:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in error()
   1784                                .format(key=key,
-> 1785                                        axis=self.obj._get_axis_name(axis)))
   1786 

KeyError: 'the label [3.02] is not in the [index]'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-8aa3f3ce8015> in <module>()
----> 1 dre.loc['3.02']

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1476 
   1477             maybe_callable = com._apply_if_callable(key, self.obj)
-> 1478             return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
   1479 
   1480     def _is_scalar_access(self, key):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _getitem_axis(self, key, axis)
   1909 
   1910         # fall thru to straight lookup
-> 1911         self._validate_key(key, axis)
   1912         return self._get_label(key, axis=axis)
   1913 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _validate_key(self, key, axis)
   1796                 raise
   1797             except:
-> 1798                 error()
   1799 
   1800     def _is_scalar_access(self, key):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in error()
   1783                 raise KeyError(u"the label [{key}] is not in the [{axis}]"
   1784                                .format(key=key,
-> 1785                                        axis=self.obj._get_axis_name(axis)))
   1786 
   1787             try:

KeyError: 'the label [3.02] is not in the [index]'
```

Meu erro provavelmente é bastante primário, visto que sou iniciante, mas já estou há horas tentando manipular esses dados!

Obrigado pela atenção!

Comment: Não acontece aqui - como pode ver na minha resposta, não consigo reproduzir o erro. Será que é algo com o arquivo csv que está usando? Tente usar o meu arquivo csv que coloquei na resposta, veja se com ele funciona

Comment: De fato, um problema primário. Eu estava verificando o csv através de uma planilha do Calc, o que me impediu de perceber que os valores da coluna Conta estavam salvos com espaços extras - p.ex: " 3.04 ", ao invés de "3.04". Corrigi o defeito através do gedit e o DataFrame agora se comporta como o esperado. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que `.set_index()` não altera o índice do `DataFrame`, e sim, retorna um novo `DataFrame` com o índice alterado.

Troque

```
dre.set_index('Conta')
```

Para

```
dre = dre.set_index('Conta')
```

Por exemplo, criei esse arquivo `teste.csv` para testar:

```
3.01,Receita de Venda,478,355,666
3.02,Custo dos bens,-123,34234,773
3.03,Resultado bruto,456,545,234
```

Rodei esse código:

```
import pandas as pd
dre = pd.read_csv('teste.csv', 
    names=['Conta', 'Descrição', '2017', '2016', '2015'],
    dtype={'Conta':str})
dre = dre.set_index('Conta')
print(dre.loc['3.02'])
```

O resultado, conforme esperado:

```
Descrição    Custo dos bens
2017                   -123
2016                  34234
2015                    773
Name: 3.02, dtype: object
```

EDIT: Talvez sejam os espaços em branco no seu campo `Conta`, dentro do seu arquivo csv. Tente removê-los colocando o código abaixo uma linha antes do `set_index`:

```
dre['Conta'] = dre['Conta'].str.strip()
```

Comment: Entendi seu ponto e fiz a alteração. Porém, o erro persiste.

Comment: Não consigo mais reproduzir o problema @AndreGraes, está funcionando aqui. Editei minha pergunta

Comment: @AndreGraes se continua tendo erro mesmo após a alteração, por favor, edite a pergunta e coloque a nova mensagem de erro completa, com traceback

Comment: @AndreGraes editei a resposta com mais uma possibilidade para consertar o problema; Verifique